# YUI 3 Uploader isuse in IE

Tags: php, javascript, yui

I am using YUI 3 Uploader.
I take this example from given reference url:
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html

I have `IE.8` version.
I have created a php file say test.php and written the script from the given url as 
given below:

```
  <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
  <script>

  YUI({filter:"raw"}).use('uploader', function(Y) {
  Y.one("#overallProgress").set("text", "Uploader type: " + Y.Uploader.TYPE);
  if (Y.Uploader.TYPE != "none" && !Y.UA.ios) {
   var uploader = 
         new Y.Uploader({width: "250px",
               height: "35px",
               multipleFiles: true,
               swfURL: "http://localhost.com  /test/flashuploader.swf?t="  + Math.random(),
               uploadURL: "http://localhost.com/test/test.php",
               simLimit: 2,
               withCredentials: false
         });
  });
```

When I open this page in the IE, nothing happens, no file dialog box opens to select file.

If anyone has already fixed this issue, please suggest me how can i solve?

Thanks,

Comment: http://localhost.com  /test/flashuploader.swf ia not valid url in IE (the space). Also is not clear if it is working in other browser or not? Because you do not pasted the whole code, just the initializer, where are the events attached?

Comment: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html this is working on ie8, just tested. Compare what you have with the full source from there

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I am using whole code given by URL (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html) . but still is not working.

Comment: when I open this page,
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html.
no option comes to select file. i clicked on select files but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   I have used all source code from below url:
   http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-multiple.html

   and 
   <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
   to    create instance the uploader.

   We need to just replace another version file of yui-min.js file as below
   <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>

   Apart from js file we need to change these 
   swfUrl: http://mudomain.com/test/flashuploader.swf
   UploadeUrl: http://mudomain.com/test/uploader.php

   To Upload file on the server, just write the script in the given above page in
    the  uploadUrl "uploader.php" as

   <?php
   $uploadedPath = 'Uploaded_Files/';
    foreach ($_FILES as $fieldName => $file) {
       move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadedPath.$file['name']);
    }
    ?>

    Now you will see all selected files will be uploaded.

   But there is limitation in the IE, We can upload 1 to 5 files at a time.
```